# Express returns 404 error when changing code or refreshing in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a Express backend server and React frontend server.
I divided path into "/react" path to show react file and "/" path for express.
Each path works if I don't change the react code or refresh react page. But If I do these two things, react path doesn't show webpage.
In terminal, sometimes it seems that there're no problems with server & client(returns 200 code) but server intermittently returns "GET /react/static/js/bundle.js.map/", "GET /ws" 404 error. In both cases, webpage is not shown anyway. so it's so difficult to proceed with development in React. I don't want to modify the settings related to building bc the project is not in the deployment stage yet.

I tried to merge both paths or apply proxy to React etc. but all failed. I assuming there's a problem with the server and client connection, but haven't solved it all day in a few days...
Thanks a lot in advance for any help you can give!

app.js in server

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var fs = require("fs");

var userRouter = require("./routes/user");
require("dotenv").config();

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port);

app.set("etag", false);


// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get("/react", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/public/index.html"));
  res.end();
});
const options = { etag: false };
app.use(
  "/react",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/public"), options)
);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/main.html"));
});
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), options));

app.use("/user", userRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

package.json in server

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "ioredis": "^5.3.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "redis": "^4.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  }
}
```

package.json in front

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "/react",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.8",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.18.1",
    "camelcase": "^6.2.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-resolve": "^27.4.2",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.1",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.3.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.8",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "resolve": "^1.20.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "swiper": "^9.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ],
    "resetMocks": true
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is package.json in project root folder and I couldn't use dev command due to "port is already in use" error. I run server and client commands separately. I think it was already wrong from the beginning...

```
{
  "name": "back-test-workspace",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "init": "cd client && npm install && cd server && npm install",
    "client": "npx kill-port 3000 && cd client && npm run start",
    "server": "npx kill-port 4000 && cd server && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I imagine you are routing your react application using react-router-dom? Those routes will need to be captured in your express website too.

Comment: @SteveTomlin You’re right, I’m routing those paths using react-router-dom only. I also tried to use app.use(”*”,~) in server to grant routing privileges to the React, but failed and didn’t try again. If it fails, the server should have caught those routes... Thank you a lot!  I'll try again.